# LiveVideo.js is not working in asp.net mvc3 but html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, webgl, three.js, live-video

I have a html page that shows a canvas and live video streaming as a texture input by livevideo.js and three.js files. This html page works fine but not in mvc-3 view page in a form of cshtml.  All I noticed is that this message below as a warning:

WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: generateMipmap: level 0 not power of 2 or not all the same size

Why this is working in regular html page in iis server but not in mvc3 view page?
I did not have any error yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the request made to the html and the mvc app (for instance, using fiddler), you will see the differences between both responses. I think probably there's a different header between them.

Comment: Good point. but nothing differ from each other when I added console comments to see the progress by javascript. No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with video texture. What you need to do is to avoid using mipmaps when texture is not power of 2 which are enabled by default:

```
_tmpTex.generateMipmaps = false;
_tmpTex.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
_tmpTex.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```